# Unexpected token 'export' when importing hanko-elements in SvelteKit app

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I want to integrate authentication with Hanko in my SvelteKit app. Following the guide https://docs.hanko.io/guides/svelte I do

```
import { register } from '@teamhanko/hanko-elements';
```

and get the following error:

> Unexpected token 'export'

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: Just noticed that it works when I turn SSR off (i.e. add a file `+layout.ts` with the following line: `export const ssr = false;`)

Answer (score 2):

You may consider importing the package asynchronsly inside the `onMount` lifecycle hook, ex:

```
onMount(()=>{
  import('@teamhanko/hanko-elements').then((mod) => {
    console.log(mod.register)
  });
})
```

Another option would be to add the dependency that causes the issue to `ssr => noExternal` array in `vite.config.ts` like following:

```
import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [sveltekit()],
    ssr: {
        noExternal: ['@teamhanko/hanko-elements']
    },
    test: {
        include: ['src/**/*.{test,spec}.{js,ts}']
    }
});
```